# Displaying API Data in View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm retrieving the data but can't seem to figure out how to show it on the View as a list, this is the model:

```
struct APIResponce: Codable {
//    var id = UUID()
    let data: ApiDataClass
    let error: Bool
}

struct ApiDataClass: Codable {
    let address, quote_currency: String
    let chain_id: Int
    let items: [ApiItems]
}

struct ApiItems: Codable {
    let contract_decimals: Int32
    let contract_name, contract_ticker_symbol, contract_address, logo_url, type, balance: String
    let supports_erc: [String]?
    let quote_rate: Double?
    let quote: Double
}
```

When I try something like:

```
VStack {
    List(apiManager.blockchainData!, id: \.items) { item in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(item.contract_ticker_symbol)
                .font(.headline)
            Text(item.quote)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Key path value type '_' cannot be converted to contextual type '_'
```

If I create a button and do:

```
for data in apiManager.blockchainData!.items {
    print(data.contract_ticker_symbol)
}
```

it would work, but I can't display on the view, some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not clear what your question is, but if you are trying to show the list of ApiItems, make your struct Hashable, and then just do this:

```
    VStack {
        List(apiManager.blockchainData!.items, id: \.self) { item in 
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.contract_ticker_symbol).font(.headline)
                Text(String(item.quote))  // <-- note the String here
            }
        }
    }
```

Note, you should not use the "!" as you do in List(...).

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I try that it compiles but at execution crashes with error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` why? The error comes from the `!` on the line: `List(apiManager.blockchainData!.items, id: \.self) { item in`

Comment: Never mind, got it to work like this: `apiManager.blockchainData?.items ?? [], id: \.self) { item in` thanks for the help!